# Что такое плоский код?

Tags: java, терминология, чистый-код

Хорошо писать плоский код или плохо? Есть примеры плоского кода на Java?
Может кто-нибудь знает, почему он так называется?

Comment: Есть метка "любой-язык".

Comment: @maestro ну, меня интересует это в Java

Comment: Может укажете где Вы столкнулись с использованием этого термина и в каком контексте?

Comment: @defaultlocale https://toster.ru/q/569396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плоский или линейный код - это код, в котором операции выполняются последовательно без вложенности конструкций, например:

```
a.soSmth(1, 2, 3);
b = a.clone();
b.doSmth(4, 5, 6);
c.setX(311);
```

Comment: при использовании if код автоматический становится не плоским?

Comment: @Grundy, вроде да?